# Why am I receiving continuous 524 Error through Cloudflare?

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare

Got a site that is running cloudflare that continuously gives a 524 error. I know that the 524 error is caused by the successful connection to the origin web server, but the origin did not provide an HTTP response before the default 100 second connection timed out.

The issue is stemming only when updating pages or article following this pattern.

1. Edit document (no issue)
2. Save document (no issue)
3. Return back to the list of articles or blogs posted (Timed out request.)

Any body have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most typical cause of this is indeed that the server is returning no response within the allotted timeframe. A HTTP 524 error is one provided by CloudFlare specifically because they have determined there is "nothing to serve".

One of the most common causes for this is a fatal error in the PHP runtime however, `display_errors` is disabled in your PHP configuration, resulting in nothing returned.

To effectively troubleshoot this, you should:

1. Enable `display_errors` in your PHP configuration. (Ask your System Administrator for assistance with this)
2. Temporarily bypass CloudFlare. This allows for errors that can't leak through CloudFlare to bubble-up.
3. Inspect your PHP `error_log` files, and also your Apache error logs. These usually hold key information unlocking the mystery of the error.
4. Reach out to your Web Host or a qualified System Administrator who can investigate this in closer detail for you.

I'm sorry that my answer is fairly broad however, there's no hard and fast answer as to why a HTTP 524 is occurring.